# Pygame: Flipping horizontally

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm making a game for my program and I'm trying to flip the image horizontally when I press the left key or right key. I found out about the function

```
pygame.transform.flip
```

however I am unsure as to where to insert it in my code. It would be appreciated if someone could help me. Here is my code. Also could somebody also tell me how I could prevent the image from moving out of the screen?

```
import pygame
import os

img_path = os.path.join('C:\Python27', 'player.png')

class Player(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def handle_keys(self):
        """ Handles Keys """
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
            self.y += dist 
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]: 
            self.y -= dist 
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
            self.x += dist 
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist
)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 400))

player = Player() 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()      # quit the screen
            running = False

    player.handle_keys()       # movement keys

    screen.fill((255,255,255)) # fill the screen with white
    player.draw(screen)        # draw the player to the screen
    pygame.display.update()    # update the screen

    clock.tick(60)             # Limits Frames Per Second to 60 or less
```

Comment: You have something doing when left or right key is pressed... And you want to flip when left or right key is pressed... It would make sense to put it there would it not ? As for image going off screen. it's called edge detection.

Comment: Keeping the image on screen should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the image processing stuff when Player is instantiated like so:

```
class Player(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
        self.image2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.flipped = False
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
```

Handle keys would changed the state of self.flipped.

```
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
        self.x += dist
        self.flipped = False
    elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.x -= dist
        self.flipped = True
```

Then self.draw decides which image to display.

```
def draw(self, surface):
    if self.flipped:
        image = self.image2
    else:
        image = self.image
    surface.blit(image, (self.x, self.y))
```

This is the approach I take with all animated game objects.